# Finding features of connected lines to simplify line elements

Tags: r, line, sf, nearest-neighbor

I have a dataset of spatial line element where each line is classified as a certain vegetation type. The issue is that there are quite few instances where different vegetation types are recorded for the same line element. For example, line element A was classified as vegetation type 1 and as vegetation type 2. Line element A is therefore recorded twice in the database.

My goal is to simplify the data further by having only one vegetation type for each line element. My approach is to check the neighbouring, touching lines and check what vegetation type was recorded for those line elements. To illustrate, if the connecting / touching line elements all are vegetation type 2, then I want to select that vegetation type for the line element A. I want to do this for all line elements where more than one vegetation type was recorded.

I am not sure how to go about this. My first guess is to identify the connecting feautres of the lines with more than one vegetation type and somehow relate the vegetation type of the connection features. My preferred way is in R, but I'm also happy with a solution in QGIS.

Example dataset

```
structure(list(veg_type = c(1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1), geometry = structure(list(
structure(c(256467.281296153, 256461.531311035, 526555.12499461, 
526505.875122078), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
"sfg")), structure(c(256461.531297717, 256442.203125007, 
526505.875014715, 526348.312683105), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(256442.203125007, 256428.421875011, 
526348.312500004, 526230.00012207), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(256417.468689889, 256433.437487505, 
526217.562507417, 526347.000020735), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(256417.468689889, 256433.437487505, 
526217.562507417, 526347.000020735), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(256433.437500004, 256457.578308105, 
526347.000122074, 526557.687500007), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(256457.578125004, 256479.218676165, 
526557.687500007, 526754.375008311), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(256467.281311039, 256492.01568513, 
526555.125122067, 526754.562492598), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(
input = "Amersfoort / RD New", wkt = "PROJCRS[\"Amersfoort / RD New\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"Amersfoort\",\n        DATUM[\"Amersfoort\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"Bessel 1841\",6377397.155,299.1528128,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4289]],\n    CONVERSION[\"RD New\",\n        METHOD[\"Oblique Stereographic\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9809]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",52.1561605555556,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",5.38763888888889,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.9999079,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",155000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",463000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"easting (X)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"northing (Y)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Engineering survey, topographic mapping.\"],\n        AREA[\"Netherlands - onshore, including Waddenzee, Dutch Wadden Islands and 12-mile offshore coastal zone.\"],\n        BBOX[50.75,3.2,53.7,7.22]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",28992]]"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_LINESTRING","sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 256417.468689889, ymin = 526217.562507417, xmax = 256492.01568513, ymax = 526754.562492598), class = "bbox"))), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(bermtype = NA_integer_), levels = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"))
```

Comment: Could you provide a brief example of your data? Please consider copy/pasting a portion of your dataset as serialized by `base::dput()` so that we can have a "hang" of your data. The question as it stands now feels a bit fluffy...

Comment: I added a very basic sample of my dataset.

Comment: In your data lines in row 4 and 5 are perfectly overlapping, so you want to de-duplicate that and record their veg_type as two rows in a separate lookup-table? Is that the sort of data structure you need?

Comment: Not exactly. I want to de-duplicate and in the end have a single veg_typ per record. But to decide which record should stay, I want to check it's connecting features and see 1) if a single veg_type was recorded. If all it's connecting features are tof the same veg_type then the record in between those two features should also get that veg_type if it is one of the two veg_types that was recorded for the perfectly overlapping records. Put it differently, if everything around a particular feature is of a certain veg_type, then that middle feature should also change to that veg_type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the "surrounding" of a line as a spatial buffer, you can first identify duplicated lines, get all lines within a defined spatial distance, and then apply a function (e.g. a custom mode function) to decide for a specific value.

```r
data
#> Simple feature collection with 8 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 256417.5 ymin: 526217.6 xmax: 256492 ymax: 526754.6
#> Projected CRS: Amersfoort / RD New
#>   veg_type                       geometry
#> 1        1 LINESTRING (256467.3 526555...
#> 2        1 LINESTRING (256461.5 526505...
#> 3        4 LINESTRING (256442.2 26348....
#> 4        1 LINESTRING (256417.5 526217...
#> 5        4 LINESTRING (256417.5 526217...
#> 6        1 LINESTRING (256433.4 526347...
#> 7        1 LINESTRING (256457.6 526557...
#> 8        1 LINESTRING (256467.3 526555...

# lets define a custom mode function
mode_vec <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

# find identical lines and subset the data object
is_equal <- st_equals(data)
lengths <- sapply(is_equal, length)
data_unique <- data[which(lengths == 1), ]
data_non_unique <- data[which(lengths != 1), ]

# we need only to iterate over the non-unique features
indices <- unique(st_equals(data_non_unique))

# let's define the size of the spatial buffer
buffer <- 10 # CRS units, here meters

# now we query all lines within the buffer for 
# non-unique lines and calculate the mode value
data_mode <- lapply(indices, function(is, var){
  target <- data_non_unique[is[1], ] 
  target_buffer <- st_buffer(target, buffer)
  row_ids <- unlist(st_intersects(target_buffer, data))
  values <- data[["veg_type"]][row_ids] 
  mode_value <- mode_vec(values)
  target[["veg_type"]] <- mode_value
  target
})


data_mode <- do.call(rbind, data_mode)
(data_new <- rbind(data_unique, data_mode))
#> Simple feature collection with 7 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 256417.5 ymin: 26348.31 xmax: 256492 ymax: 526754.6
#> Projected CRS: Amersfoort / RD New
#>   veg_type                       geometry
#> 1        1 LINESTRING (256467.3 526555...
#> 2        1 LINESTRING (256461.5 526505...
#> 3        4 LINESTRING (256442.2 26348....
#> 6        1 LINESTRING (256433.4 526347...
#> 7        1 LINESTRING (256457.6 526557...
#> 8        1 LINESTRING (256467.3 526555...
#> 4        1 LINESTRING (256417.5 526217...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

So there is possibly a better/faster way to do it but here is how I have done it. Read in your data above as `data`.

```
###library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(sf)
library(dbscan)

data$unique_ids <- 1:nrow(data)

###find duplicated rows
is_dup_row <- duplicated(data$geometry)
is_dup_row

###remove duplicated rows
no_dups <- data[!is_dup_row,]

###get pt coords for start and end of all lines
data_coords_no_dups = data.frame(st_coordinates(st_cast(no_dups$geometry,"LINESTRING")))

###remove automatic numbering
data_coords_no_dups$L1 <- NULL

##paste in unique id per point
data_pt_unique_ids <- sort(c(no_dups$unique_ids, no_dups$unique_ids))
data_coords_no_dups$unique_ids <- data_pt_unique_ids

###paste in veg type
###this is probably a slow method for a lot of points
veg_type_pts <- NULL
for( i in 1:nrow(no_dups)){
  veg_type <- no_dups$veg_type[i]
  veg <- c(veg_type, veg_type)
veg_type_pts <- c(veg_type_pts, veg)  
}

###merge veg type per pt
data_coords_no_dups$veg_type_pts <- veg_type_pts

###get the k nearest neighbours for all pts
knn_data  <- kNN(data_coords_no_dups, 3)
knn_data$id

###get the veg type for each nearest neighbour. you need to put this into a different df as we need to convert to pivot longer to be able to get the median of multiple cols in summary
data_coords_no_dups$NN_1_vegtype <- data_coords_no_dups$veg_type_pts[knn_data$id[,1]]
data_coords_no_dups$NN_2_vegtype <- data_coords_no_dups$veg_type_pts[knn_data$id[,2]]
data_coords_no_dups$NN_3_vegtype <- data_coords_no_dups$veg_type_pts[knn_data$id[,3]]

data_coords_no_dups %>%
  select(unique_ids, NN_1_vegtype, NN_2_vegtype, NN_3_vegtype) -> data_coords_no_dups_subset

###pivot longer
data_coords_no_dups_subset %>%
  pivot_longer(!unique_ids, names_to = "Veg_type", values_to = "count") -> data_coords_no_dups_subset_long

###need to define mode
mode <- function(codes){
  which.max(tabulate(codes))
}

###summarise
data_coords_no_dups_subset_long %>%
  group_by(unique_ids) %>%
  summarise(new_veg_type = mode(count)) -> new_data

###if you want you can paste the new veg type to the original data
no_dups$new_veg_type <- new_data$new_veg_type
```